# Receive delegate method calls from multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an app with a `SplitViewController`. The `MasterViewController` is a `UITableViewController`. And the `DetailViewController` is a `UIViewController` with a `MapView`.

[image]

I'm calling an API to get a list of events. In the tableView, I want to display the names and the addresses of the events. And in the mapView, I want to mark the locations of those events.

I have a class called `DataLoader` in which I call the API, parse the JSON object and create `Event` objects and put them in an array successfully.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

@objc protocol DataLoaderDelegate {
    func eventDataReceived(items: [Event]?, error: NSError?)
}

public class DataLoader {

    private let api = ApiClient()

    var delegate: DataLoaderDelegate?

    init() { }

    public func fetchEvents() {
        api.getEvents({ (data) -> Void in
            let json = JSON(data)
            self.processEventData(json["data"])
        }, failure: { (error) -> Void in
            println("Error fetching events: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            self.delegate?.eventDataReceived(nil, error: error)
        })
    }

    private func processEventData(data: JSON) {
        var events = [Event]()

        if let eventsArray = data.array {
            for eventObj in eventsArray {
                let event = Event(
                    id: eventObj["id"].int!,
                    type: EventType(rawValue: eventObj["type"].int!)!,
                    location: eventObj["location"].string!,
                    status: EventStatus(rawValue: eventObj["status"].int!)!
                )
                event.allDay = eventObj["allDay"].int!
                event.title = eventObj["title"].string
                event.description = eventObj["description"].string
                event.latitude = eventObj["lat"].double
                event.longitude = eventObj["lng"].double
                event.startDate = NSDate(string: eventObj["start"].string!)
                event.endDate = NSDate(string: eventObj["end"].string!)
                event.createdAtDate = NSDate(string: eventObj["created_at"].string!)
                event.updatedAtDate = NSDate(string: eventObj["updated_at"].string!)
                event.creatorEmail = eventObj["creatorEmail"].string
                event.organizerEmail = eventObj["organizerEmail"].string
                event.googleCalendarId = eventObj["google_cal_id"].string!
                event.googleEventId = eventObj["google_event_id"].string!
                event.htmlLink = eventObj["htmlLink"].string!

                events.append(event)
            }

            // Order the events by the startDate value
            events.sort({ $0.startDate!.timeIntervalSince1970 < $1.startDate!.timeIntervalSince1970 })

            self.delegate?.eventDataReceived(events, error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I have a delegate called `DataLoaderDelegate` with a method called `func eventDataReceived(items: [Event]?, error: NSError?)` which is called after all the event objects are inserted into an array so I can pass it through that method.

I need this method implemented in both the `ListViewController` where I populate the tableView and `MapViewController` where I populate the mapView. So I have implemented the `eventDataReceived` delegate method in both view controllers in order to get the events objects.

**ListViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ListViewController: UITableViewController, DataLoaderDelegate {

    let loader = DataLoader()

    private var events = [Event]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loader.delegate = self
        loader.fetchEvents()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return events.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        let event = events[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = event.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = event.location

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - DataLoaderDelegate
    func eventDataReceived(items: [Event]?, error: NSError?) {
        println("ListViewController got \(items?.count) events")
        if let events = items {
            self.events = events
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

**MapViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, DataLoaderDelegate {

    let loader = DataLoader()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loader.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: - DataLoaderDelegate
    func eventDataReceived(items: [Event]?, error: NSError?) {
        println("MapViewController got \(items?.count) events")
    }
}
```

But here's the problem. Only the implementation in the `ListViewController` gets executed. I think the reason is I create a new instance of `DataLoader` class in the `MapViewController`.

What should I do to have one instance of `DataLoader` across the entire application and receive its delegate method calls from all view controllers?

I've uploaded a demo project to my [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/83o1greu2oec1t3/DataLoader.zip?dl=0) if you need to run it to get a better idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a best-practice case for a [Singleton-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)
Your DataLoader should implement a static let holding the reference to the same object of self.

```
static let sharedInstance = DataLoader()
```

When you want the reference to constantly the same singleton-object. Call it with `DataLoader.sharedInstance`

Make sure to always use .sharedInstance then and do not forget to wipe any calls of the standard initializer of the class, because it will still make new instances unless you block this behavior programmatically.

**Explained**

Only inserting the singleton constant (shown above) will NOT make DataLoader class always return the singleton instance. The existing initializer calls like:

```
   var myDataLoader = DataLoader()
```

will still instanciate a new object, everytime they are called. The singleton instance is reached with:

```
   var mySingletonDataLoader = DataLoader.sharedInstance
```

You could change your standard (non singleton) initializers like:

```
init() {
NSLog("No instances allowed, please use .sharedInstance for a singleton")
}
```

**Complete solution**

The singleton is only one piece to solve the whole problem. The used delegate-pattern works great for sending information from one object to another and therefore delegating the work. 
The problem from the questioner needs another broadcasting mechanism from one object to many other object. Therefore he decided to implement the [Observer-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) with [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that. By the way can you please elaborate a little on this part? > wipe any calls of the standard initializer of the class. An example would be really helpful if you could.

Comment: Thanks. I made the necessary changes you've mentioned but when I refer the properties (the `delegate` property) and methods (`fetchEvents()`) from the view controller, I still get the error message inside the `init` method. [Here](http://pastie.org/10180908) is my code.

Comment: every call of `DataLoader.sharedInstance.delegate` overwrites the old delegate. Only the latest delegate will be called. The singleton pattern is the correct way to go, but delegation might not be the right one. You should be going with the [Observer-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: I used `NSNotificationCenter` and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Good approach. I updated the answer to blend your info in

Comment: FYI an alternate implementation of init would be to return sharedInstance (if non-nil).  That is valid ObjC although I expect the result would be more confusing then an error message & abort.